# Wordpress Flex Slider Change Stock Images

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, flexslider

I know this isn't strictly a programming question but I don't know where else to ask

I downloaded this theme for my wordpress site, it comes with a flex slider

I've added a flex slider to my static page

[image]

and I've tried to add some posts to the flex slider section but I don't know how to change the images on the flex slider

[image]

please help, it would save me so much time!! Thank you very much

Comment: did you post this to the wordpress forums?

Comment: thanks for your reply! It said i need to log on to wordpress forum through my website but not sure how to do that :(

Comment: you just [make an account](https://wordpress.org/support/register.php), its free and really easy, the WP forums are awesome!